# REST API zend framework 2 migrating to REST API zend framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Currently, I am using REST API in Zend Framework 2.
Now, I want to migrate the ZF2 REST API in ZF3.
I've checked the REST API for ZF3 but did not found anything.

There is no documentation for the ZF3 REST API.

Is it possible to build the REST API using ZF3?
It will be good , if i get any example for it.

Comment: What have you tried and what's your error? Try to be as specific as possible so that the community can help you.

Comment: @RedBottle: Thanks, I've edited the question now.

Answer (score 1):

Check: https://github.com/multidots/zf3-rest-api OR

Create ur rest controller:

```
class AlbumRestController extends AbstractRestfulController
    {
        public function get($id)
        {
            return new JsonModel(array("id"));
        }

        public function getList()
        {
            return new JsonModel(
                array(
                    array("id"),
                    array("id"),
                    array("id")
                ));
        }
    }
```

Add to ur module.config.php:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\AlbumRestController::class => InvokableFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

Finally define ur routes:

```
'router' => [
    'routes' => [
        'album-rest' => [
            'type' => Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route'    => '/album-rest[/:id]',
                'constraints'=> [
                    'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\AlbumRestController::class,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```